# Bootstrap NavBar non-collapsable input field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a nav Bar with a input field and a couple links
but I want just the links to be collapsed.
I'm trying to get this work for a few hours with no success.

It doesn't stay on a single row
[image]

What I want is something like this

Desktop

```
| [Brand Name] [Input field___________________________(Search)]       [Button] [Button] |
```

Mobile

```
 | [Brand Name] [Input field     (Search)] [#] |
 |---------------------------------------------|
 |  Button                                     |
 |  Button                                     |
```

http://www.bootply.com/G1JJxeMQA0#

another atempt http://www.bootply.com/n3raobttyd

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
https://jsfiddle.net/9L3b08zf/

If you change the size of the result grid, you will see how the link will jump form side to bottom.

I have used the bootstrap grid to achieve this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 search">
     <form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g.: www.google.com" id="query" name="query" value="">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Locate</span></button>
             </div>
         </div>

      </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 buttons">
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#">Login</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-target="#">Register</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```